# What happens when fscanf doesn't find all the values as defined in the format string?

Tags: parsing, input, scanf, configuration-files

In context - I'm writing a simple, standalone config file parser for a class that will go into a larger program. I understand that there are extremely effective libraries (such as BOOST) to do this for me, but the class must be strictly stand-alone (no external libraries).

So, I have a config file that may look a little like this:

```
output_file : some_output_file.root
input_file : input_file.txt
potential_file :
```

Notice that the **potential_file** entry is blank, and should be read as such.

I intend to use fscanf, with a format specifier

```
fscanf(cfg_file,"%s : %s\n",flag,value);
```

However, what happens in the case of the **potential_file** flag? Will the character string **value** be empty? Or will fscanf try to read the next available string in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check return value of fscanf. It returns the number of arguments successfully parsed. It will not make an empty string for you if you have no space after colon in 3rd line as per pattern. It will stop parsing in that case. If you want to play safe with no extra checks, initialize value before fscanf.

`%s` implies reading of subsequent characters until a whitespace is found. The latter is defined as blank, newline, or tab. So it will not jump to next line.

Also consider some library for config since you've tagged your questions in this way. [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) is easy to read and it has C bindings.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. I understand that there are external libraries that could handle this trivially, but unfortunately I cannot use them - the code must stand entirely by itself.

Comment: If you'd like some protection against format anomalies, you'd better off reading it line by line into a buffer and then apply scanf to a line in buffer.